# Wireguard "Road Warrior" configuration

Tags: routing, vpn

The examples I see for Wireguard usually have the server specify an IP for the client but I don't want that.  I want N number of clients to be able to connect and get an IP, and to route all traffic through the server.  Just like an OpenVPN connection.

What is a good server and client `wg0.conf` example for this please?

Answer (score 0):

This is one of the major drawbacks wireguard has right now: It only supports static configurations. However there is [wg-dynamic](https://git.zx2c4.com/wg-dynamic/about/docs/idea.md), but development is seemingly stalled

Answer (score 0):

There are many widely available "road warrior" setup cookbooks that don't work. It routes all traffic thru the WireGuard server. Someone else may have set it up for multiple clients. Sorry, not me.

Try this one, it's operational and tested. Skip the first part and go to part 2:

Part 1 Summarized version, the first part is not fully functional. Proceed below to "Step by Step Guide..." for the complete procedure.

(SEE PDF AT: https://codeberg.org/kpiq/Tech-Space/src/branch/main/Resources/Firewall/OPNsense/OPNsense%20WireGuard%20Installation%20and%20Setup%20-%20Generic.pdf)

To configure WireGuard on OPNsense, the following steps need to be followed:

Install the WireGuard plugin on your OPNsense firewall by navigating to System -> Firmware -> Plugins, searching for "os-wireguard," and installing the plugin.

Generate cryptographic key pairs (public and private keys) for both the server and clients.

Configure WireGuard tunnel interfaces on both the server and clients by navigating to Interfaces -> Assignments, selecting the WireGuard device, adding a description, enabling the interface, and applying changes.

Configure firewall rules on your OPNsense WireGuard VPN server to allow clients to connect to the server and access the internal networks.

Enable WireGuard tunnel interfaces on both the server and clients by navigating to VPN -> WireGuard -> General on the OPNsense Web GUI, enabling the WireGuard server, adding a new local configuration, adding peers to the local configuration, and enabling the WireGuard server.

For more detailed information, please refer to the source [https://www.sunnyvalley.io/docs/network-security-tutorials/how-to-setup-wireguard-on-opnsense ''[1]''].

==== Sources: ====

[''https://www.sunnyvalley.io/docs/network-security-tutorials/how-to-setup-wireguard-on-opnsense'']

Part 2 Step-by-step guide for installing and configuring WireGuard on OPNsense:

CONTRARY TO MANY OUTDATED PROCEDURES, THIS ONE HAS BEEN VALIDATED. IT WORKS!

Follow guide on [''https://www.sunnyvalley.io/docs/network-security-tutorials/how-to-setup-wireguard-on-opnsense'']. The cryptographic keys for the WireGuard server instance will be auto-generated when you blank out the Public and Private Key fields in the VPN-WireGuard-Local tab.

```
HOME Network Local Configuration:

Name = homefwwg

Private key = <see Bitwarden, homefw, WG private key>

Public key = <see Bitwarden, homefw, WG public key>

Tunnel Address = 10.250.0.8/29

Listen Port = 51820

Peers = client1, client2

End Points Configuration:

Clients

Name = client1 (Android)

Public key =

AllowedIPs = 10.250.0.11/32

[WireGuard Interface]

IP Address = 10.250.0.11/32

DNS = 10.x.x.1, 10.x.x.2

Private key = <see Bitwarden, client1, WG private key>

[Peer]

Public key = <see Bitwarden, homefw, WG public key>

AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

Endpoint = home-public-ip-address:51820

Name = client2 (Windows)

Public key =

AllowedIPs = 10.250.0.10/32

[WireGuard Interface]

IP Address = 10.250.0.10/32

DNS = 10.x.x.1, 10.x.x.2

Private key = <see Bitwarden, client2, WG private key>

[Peer]

Public key = <see Bitwarden, homefw, WG public key>

AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0

PersistentKeepAlive = 25

Endpoint = home-public-ip-address:51820
```

In addition to the steps recommended in the SunnyValley guide, do the following, from the OPNsense guide for installing WireGuard (https://docs.opnsense.org/manual/how-tos/wireguard-client.html):

Create firewall rules

This will involve two steps

1. first, creating a firewall rule on the WAN interface to allow
   clients to connect to the OPNsense WireGuard server, and then
2. creating a firewall rule to allow access by the clients to whatever IPs they are intended to have access to. Go to Firewall ‣ Rules ‣ WAN.

   Click Add to add a new rule

   Configure the rule as follows (if an option is not mentioned below, leave it as the default):

   Action=Pass

   Quick=Checked

   Interface=WAN

   Direction in

   TCP/IP Version IPv4 or IPv4+IPv6 (as desired, depending on how you want clients to connect to the server; note this is distinct from what type of traffic is allowed in the tunnel once established)

   Protocol UDP Source / Invert Unchecked

   Source wg1.net ("wg1" is the WireGuard interface name auto-generated by OPNsense when adding the WireGuard service instance. It can be "wg0", "wg1", or other.)

   Destination / Invert Unchecked

   Destination WAN address

   Destination port range The WireGuard port specified in the Local configuration in Step 2

   Description Add one if you wish to

   Save the rule, and then click Apply Changes

   Then go to Firewall ‣ Rules ‣ [Name of interface assigned in Step 5(a)] - see note below if you didn’t assign this interface

   Click Add to add a new rule

   Configure the rule as follows (if an option is not mentioned below, leave it as the default):

   Action Pass

   Quick Checked

   Interface Whatever interface you are configuring the rule on (eg HomeWireGuard ) - see note below Direction in TCP/IP Version IPv4 or IPv4+IPv6 (as applicable)

   Protocol any Source / Invert Unchecked

   Source If you assigned an interface under Step 5(a), select the generated alias for the interface subnet(s) (eg HomeWireGuard net ) - see note below if you didn’t assign this interface

   Destination / Invert Unchecked

   Destination Specify the IPs that client peers should be able to access, eg “any” or specific IPs/subnets

   Destination port range any

   Description Add one if you wish to

   Save the rule, and then click Apply Changes

I keep these instructions updated at: WireGuard install and configuration on OPNsense - https://codeberg.org/kpiq/Tech-Space/wiki/WireGuard-install-and-configuration-on-OPNsense

Comment: My apologies for the low quality of my previous answer.  Thanks for the excellent job moderating the answers.